# Well defined function given by an infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

**Main Reference:** O. Christensen, K.L. Christensen, ``Approximation Theory: from Taylor Polynomials to Wavelets'',
Birkhauser, Boston, 2nd printing, 2005.

Statement of Exercise $2.11 (i)$ on p. 49: ``Prove that

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2^n x)}{3^n}, \,\, x \in \mathbb{R} $$
is well defined.''

My attempt to prove the above:

In general for a function $g: A \rightarrow B$ to be well defined, the following conditions must be satisfied:

- $g \subseteq A \times B$
- for each element $a \in A$, there is an element $b \in B$ such that
  $(a,b) \in g$
- if $(a,b),(a,c) \in g$, then $b =c$

In particular, the third condition says that if an element of $A$ has an image in $B$ then this image is unique.
$f(x)$ as given above satisfies this condition if the series is absolutely convergent. We have that ``if
$${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n}$$

is absolutely convergent with sum $X$, then every rearrangement is absolutely convergent and has sum $X$.'' (Ref: Dangello and Seyfried, ``Introductory Real Analysis'', p. 158). Suppose the infinite series for $f(x)$ is only conditionally convergent then there could be a rearrangement that gives a different sum than the original arrangement. That is for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we could have two different images.

Using the Root test we have:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left| \frac{\cos(2^n x)}{3^n} \right| } \leq  \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left| \frac{1}{3^n} \right| } = 
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{3} =  \frac{1}{3} < 1$$

So the infinite series is absolutely convergent. Therefore $f(x)$ is well defined.

I would like to know if the above proof is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think so. One alternative is to apply the comparison test:
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{\cos(2^{n}x)}{3^{n}}\right| \leq \frac{1}{3^{n}}
\end{align*}

where the last series converges because it is a geometric series with ratio $0 < r < 1$.

Hopefully this is helpful!

Comment: Yes very helpful. I agree Comparison test does work very well in this case. I am glad my argument that absolute convergence is key in showing that $f(x)$ is well defined function although as $n \rightarrow \infty$ $\cos(2^n x)$ will oscillate more and more but fortunately these oscilations are damped down by the $1/3^n$ factor.